# how to close child of other components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtXNE.png)

When I open one of three copmonent A child open,I want to close two others child if they are open.

Comment: Prior to asking Stack Overflow, you should do some research and/or attempt to solve the issue on your own. Your post does not even contain a question - it just says "This is what I want", to which the response would be... "Okay, what's stopping you?". Consider narrowing down your question by asking about a specific piece of your problem, or by including your own attempts to solve it so that we can correct them. For more information, check out the [**How To Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

Use a prop to handle the open state of each child. Pass `open={false}` to the other two children and pass `open={true}` to the child you want to open. Hard to give a meaningful answer without any code examples to work off of.

Answer (score 0):

The gist of it is

```
// where openChild is just the index of the child that should be open
// fetched from redux
// you should use an id here instead of an index
const Parent = ({ openChild }) => {
    return [0, 1, 2].map((index) => (
        <Child key={index} index={index} closed={openChild !== index}/>
    ))
}

const Child = ({ index, closed }) => {
    return <div className={closed ? 'closed' : 'open'}>{index}</div>
}
```

use `.open` and `.closed` on the child to control whether or not it's being shown or you can just conditionally render the whole thing like

```
const Parent = ({ openChild }) => {
    return [0, 1, 2].map((index) => (
        openChild !== index 
            ? <Child key={index} index={index} />
            : null
    )).filter(child => !!child)
    /* you don't really need the above line */
}
```